# IF AND with 3 conditions and 3 outcomes

Tags: excel

I need to auto calculate a student's overall grade based on completion of sub-grades

[image]

I need the grade to show:

- Pass if P = 100%
- Merit if P=100% AND m=100%
- Distinction if P=100% AND m=100% AND d=100%

Comment: what had you tried?

Comment: Will m ever equal 100% when P < 100%? Likewise for d? Because from your image it looks like you're using three fields to keep track of what's essentially one score.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(A1=100;IF(B1=100;IF(C1=100;"Distinction";"Merit");"Pass");"Looser")
```

Comment: This formula cause unwanted results because it not cover all aspects. Lets say P=100  and C=100 the formula gives Pass which is wrong.

Comment: OP not need that direction

Comment: that s why i mention it. this can lead to wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=IF(IF(AND(A2=100,B2<>100,C2<>100),"Pass",IF(AND(A2=100,B2=100,C2<>100),"Merit",IF(AND(A2=100,B2=100,C2=100),"Distinction")))=FALSE,"No Results")
```